# Mysql query not finding first word

Tags: php, mysql, database, pattern-matching

I'm building a simple search engine in `PHP` that retrieves animal names from a MySQL database when the user searches it.

Say I have the following table:

```
ID |  Name
---------------
1  |  Red panda
2  |  Okapi
3  |  Red fox
```

When the user inputs `"panda"` it returns the `Red Panda` row, when they input `"red panda"` it again returns the `Red Panda row`.

But when a user inputs `"red"` it returns nothing.

However searching `"Okapi"` does work.

For some reason searching the first word in a multiple made of multiple words doesn't return anything.

The query I'm using to find the data is the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE Name LIKE '%%$search'"
```

Comment: Share your whole code along with PHP Code and your HTML code if you have..!

Comment: try this "SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE Name LIKE '%$search%'"

Comment: @SachinVairagi is correct and it will work fine

Comment: Yeah, I did this and it works now thanks!

Comment: @Crodociles hi, it's been a while since this question got answered by a few people, to fullfil the topoc of this site you should pick an answer and accept it so that future users immediately know what helped you the mont :) have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE Name LIKE '%".$search."%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find anything which **contains** what you're searching for then you should use the `%` wildcard both before and after your `$search` in the query.

Hence you should do:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE Name LIKE %$search%";
```

The way you're currently using will match only those values which have the `$search` at the end of it.

For instance:

```
ID |  Name
---------------
1  |  Red panda
2  |  Okapi
3  |  Red fox
4  |  kaok    // added for examples
```

- matching `%ka`:

  won't return anything because `kaok` and `Okapi` have something after the `ka`. With this query you're looking for everything that **starts** with your expression;
- matching `%ka%`:

  will return both `kaok` and `Okapi`. With this query you're looking for everything that **contains** your expression;
- matching `ka%`:

  will return only `kaok`. With this query you're looking for everything that **ends** with your expression.

Take a look at the [MySQL Dev guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) about pattern matching.

Of course, as pointed out by Elzo Valugi, in his answer you need to remember to sanitise your inputs to avoid SQL Injections.

Answer (score 0):

You placed a wildcard at the begin of your like string, so you will find any names which **end** with the search term.

To search for all names which **contain** the search term add a wildcard at the end of the like string:

```
LIKE '%$search%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns nothing because your SQL Query needs to be modified slightly:

Change this

```
"SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE Name LIKE '%%$search'"
```

to this:

```
"SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE Name LIKE '%$search%'"
```

By adding % on both sides of the searched string, your database will look for any column value that has that word inserted into it.

Let me know if that solved it for you or if there are any more issues!

Comment: Thanks this seems to have fixed it!

Comment: @Crodociles No problem! if my solution is the one that worked for you, please accept it (green check mark) so that future users know that it worked when reading the thread :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

% wildcard should be like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE Name LIKE '%$search%'";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809684/mysql-query-not-finding-first-word/36809695#comment61192416_36809734

Answer (score 0):

A side note, do not aggregate the user input directly to an SQL query. This is totally unsafe practice and leads to SQL injection, in fact all examples shown here are bad practice. Use [binding](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) parameters to create your query using mysqli or PDO.

```
$search = "%". "your_search_term" . "%";
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT *
    FROM example_table
    WHERE name like :search');
$sth->bindParam(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been issue with select query.You have to change select query only.

```
select * from tbl_pets where name like "%'".$data."'%"
```

and real mysql query

```
 select * from tbl_pets where name like "%red%"
```

You can take a look here.I have created schema from that you can also check.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c08b0/1